# What are the issues that will be difficult to change once software is built?

Tags: architecture, software-design

Software architecture focuses on "Issues that will be difficult or impossible to change once the software is built." How is this statement justified?

Comment: with feedback , and reported issues

Comment: Well why would you spend time on the things that are *easy* to change once the software is built? They're easy to change, you can change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things that are easy and cheap to change, like individual functions, page layouts, fields... More difficult is the overall design and infrastructure.  If you start out with a relational model, and after the software is built, decide to switch to a NOSQL model, it's going to be expensive.  If you designed your software to be a monolith, and then switch to microservices, it's going to be expensive.  If you build an object-oriented design, and you switch to functional design, it's going to be expensive.

Those decisions are architectural, and should be made as early in the project as possible.